# Android - How to avoid editText + send button "hiding" webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I would like to know (if is possible) how to avoid the EditText and Send Button hide my webview.

Here is the screenshot (I think is better to understand what I mean):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/chat_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:hint="Type your message" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text=">" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas or solutions will be appreciated

Comment: can't getting you ? :(

Comment: Look at my screenshot .. my editText is hidding part of my webview..

Comment: Is your issue solved or do you need further assistance? Please don't forget to up vote and/or accept the answer which was most helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah, Just tried! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `RelativeLayout` you can specify if a `View` is supposed to be above another `View` with `android:layout_above`, I modified your layout so the `WebView` will always be above the `LinearLayout` at the bottom. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llFooter">
    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/llFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:hint="Type your message">
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:text=">">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically I just gave the `LinearLayout` and id so I can reference it. I then added `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to the `WebView` to make it align with the top of the screen. Then by adding `android:layout_above="@+id/llFooter"` I told the `WebView` it should extend down until reaching the `LinearLayout`. The `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the `LinearLayout` is positioning the `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the screen so as a result the `WebView` will extend from the top down to the bottom until reaching the `LinearLayout`.